# Whats the url to access static images on my heroku app

Tags: django, heroku

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", hello.views.index, name="index"),
    path("donate/", hello.views.donate, name="donate"),
    path("account/", hello.views.account, name="account"),
    path("random-tweet/", hello.views.randomtweet, name="random-tweet"),
    path("random-account/", hello.views.randomaccount, name="random-account"),
    path("db/", hello.views.db, name="db"),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^celery-progress/', include('celery_progress.urls'))
]
```

I'm trying to access an image file on my heroku app via url, something like http://www.rndtwitr.herokuapp.com/ChaosStar.png

Even though i have copied the image to the 'root' directory(i.e. the directory index.html is in) it is still not allowing me to access the image. Maybe I am misunderstanding how heroku directory structure works. Where to copy image files to on my heroku app and what is the url to access it??